# How to solve IE display google map incorrectly using iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

trying to solve IE issue where by the Google map is rendered incorrect an in google chrome and Firefox is fine,  below is the image of how it is displaying in IE:

[image]

I will be happy if you can help me solve this issue.

Comment: can you give us your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#PropertySearchMap').css({
        "position": "absolute !important",
        "left": "-10000px !important"
    });
    if ($('#PropertySearchMap').is(':visible')) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Initialize()
        }, 500);
        jQuery('#PropertySearchMap').show();
        jQuery('#PropertySearchMap').css({
            "position": "static !important"
        });
    }
});

function Initialize() {
    $("#butSearch").click(function (e) {
        ls.mapping.search();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#butReset").click(function (e) {
        var loc = document.location.href.toString().split("#");
        document.location = loc[0];
    });
    $("#butAdd").click(function (e) {
        parent.$("@Model.Source.GetTag()").trigger("property:selected", {
            propertyId: 0
        });
    });
    $("footer").hide();
    $('#select_all').click(function () {
        var c = this.checked;
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', c);
    });
    $(".body-content").css("height", "100%");
    $(".body-content").css("width", "100%");
    ls.rootUrl = "@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["
    PropertyServiceUrl "]";
    ls.mapping.initiAutoComplete();@
    if (Model.DisableMap) {@: ls.mapping.disableClickSearch = true;
    }@
    if (Model.HideSearchControls && Model.DisableMap) {@: ls.mapping.initializeMap(true);
    } else {@: ls.mapping.initializeMap(false);
    }@ if (Model.Source == MapSourceEnum.CompSales) {
        //@:window.setTimeout(ls.mapping.plotCompsales, 1000); Stephan - verify this is required
        @: ls.mapping.plotCompsales();
    }@ {@: ls.mapping.propertySelectedEventTarget = "@Model.Source.GetTag()";
    }
    ls.tools.initToolFuncs();
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcel thank you for that but i have tried that before it did not work but thanks any way.